# 302 Redirect in xhr request

Tags: python, http, scrapy

i need to send a post request to this url :

```
http://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax
```

you can see the other parameters send by this request here:

```
formdata:

filter_score:
sort:reviewed_at
duration:0
page:1
base_location_id:1

request header: 

:authority:lastsecond.ir
:method:POST
:path:/hotels/ajax
:scheme:https
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7
content-length:67
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie:_jsuid=2453861291; read_announcements=,11,11; _ga=GA1.2.2083988810.1511607903; _gid=GA1.2.1166842676.1513922852; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlZ2TklPcnFWU3AzMlVVa0k3a2xcL2dnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImVjVmt2c05STWRTUnJod1IwKzRPNk4wS2lST0k1UTk2czZwZXJxT2FQNmppNkdUSFdPK29kU29RVHlXbm1McTlFSlM5VlIwbGNhVUozbXFBbld5c2tRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4YmNiMGQwMzdlZDgyZTE2YWNlMWY1YjdmMzViNDQwMmRjZGE4YjFmMmM1ZmUyNTQ0NmE1MGRjODFiNjMwMzMwIn0%3D; lastsecond-session=eyJpdiI6ImNZQjdSaHhQM1lZaFJIZzhJMWJXN0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK1NWdHJiUTdZQzBYeEsyUjE3QXFhUGJrQXBGcExDMVBXTjhpSVJLRlFnUjVqXC9USHBxNGVEZ3dwKzVGcG5yeU93VTZncG9wRGpvK0VpVnQ2b1ByVnh3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI4NTFkYmQxZTFlMTMxOWFmZmU1ZjA1ZGZhNTMwNDFmZmU0N2FjMGVjZTg1OGU2NGE0YTNmMTc2MDA5NWM1Njg3In0%3D
origin:https://lastsecond.ir
referer:https://lastsecond.ir/hotels?score=&page=1&sort=reviewed_at&duration=0
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token:oMpQTG0wN0YveJIk2WhkesvzjZE2FqHkDqPiW8Dy
x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest
```

the result of this code suppose to be a json file, by it redirect the request to the its parent url. i'm using scrapy with python to send this request, here is scrapy code :

```
class HotelsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hotels'
    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']
    start_urls = ['http://lastsecond.ir/hotels']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            'filter_score': '',
            'sort': 'reviewed_at',
            'duration': '0',
            'page': '1',
            'base_location_id': '1'
        }
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'x-csrf-token': 'oMpQTG0wN0YveJIk2WhkesvzjZE2FqHkDqPiW8Dy',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
        url = 'https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax'
        return FormRequest(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse_details,
            formdata=data,
            method="POST",
            headers=headers,
            dont_filter=True
        )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        data = response.body_as_unicode()
        print(data)
        #f = open('output.json', 'w')
        #f.write(data)
        #f.close()
```

---

i've changed my code so it gets the fresh csrf-token everytime it sends a request:

```
class HotelsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'hotels'
    allowed_domains = ['lastsecond.ir']
    start_urls = ['http://lastsecond.ir/hotels']

    def parse(self, response):
        html = response.body_as_unicode()
        start = html.find("var csrftoken = '")
        start = start + len(b"var csrftoken = '")
        end = html.find("';", start)

        self.csrftoken = html[start:end]

        print('csrftoken:', self.csrftoken)
        yield self.ajax_request('1')

    def ajax_request(self, page):
        data = {
            'filter_score': '',
            'sort': 'reviewed_at',
            'duration': '0',
            'page': page,
            'base_location_id': '1'
        }
        headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'x-csrf-token': self.csrftoken,
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
        url = 'https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax'
        return FormRequest(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse_details,
            formdata=data,
            method="POST",
            headers=headers,
            dont_filter=True
        )

    def parse_details(self, response):
        print(response.body_as_unicode())
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: every request need new uniqe `'x-csrf-token'`  - you can't use always the same. See my answer to previous question - I do `GET` to get new `'x-csrf-token'` from `HTML`.

Comment: NEVER change question. Now my answer doesn't fit to your problem. If you changed code and still have problem then append to original question or create new question.

Comment: i fixed the question as you said, sorry for changing the original question. can you please guide me now ?

Comment: I tried your code as standalone script and I get correct result. Maybe there is different problem. Maybe server blocks you for some reason - it doesn't like your IP, or you made many requests and it knows that you run script. in `parse_details` you can try `from scrapy.commands.view import open_in_browser ; open_in_browser(response)` and it should display HTML (which you get after 302) in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making an Illegal Request? The easiest way to learn it is to copy the request in the browser as curl (`F12 -> Network -> Right Click` on specify request `-> Copy -> Copy as Curl`), and convert it to python language with [this tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/) (without Scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the same `'x-csrf-token'` in every request.

`'x-csrf-token'` is method to block bots/scripts.

Wikipedia: [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)

Every time you open page in browser portal generates new, uniqe `'x-csrf-token'` which can be correct only for short time. You can't use the same `'x-csrf-token'` all the time.

In answer to previous question I make `GET` request to get page and to find fresh `X-CSRF-TOKEN`.

See `self.csrftoken` in code

```
def parse(self, response):
    print('url:', response.url)

    html = response.body_as_unicode()

    start = html.find("var csrftoken = '")
    start = start + len(b"var csrftoken = '")
    end = html.find("';" , start)

    self.csrftoken = html[start:end]

    print('csrftoken:', self.csrftoken)

    yield self.create_ajax_request('1')
```

And later I use this token to read AJAX requests.

```
def create_ajax_request(self, page):
    ''' 
    subfunction can't use `yield, it has to `return` Request to `parser`
    and `parser` can use `yield`
    '''

    print('yield page:', page)

    url = 'https://lastsecond.ir/hotels/ajax'

    headers = {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': self.csrftoken,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }

    params = {
        'filter_score': '',
        'sort': 'reviewed_at',
        'duration': '0',
        'page': page,
        'base_location_id': '1',
    }

    return scrapy.FormRequest(url, 
        callback=self.parse_details, 
        formdata=params, 
        headers=headers, 
        dont_filter=True, 
    )
```

Comment: thank you for your helpful answer, i edited my code so it gets the fresh csrf token every time, but still getting 302 redirect and html response.